# RethinkDB on Android - compilation fails

Tags: java, android, gradle, rethinkdb

In build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.rethinkdb', name: 'rethinkdb-driver', version: '2.3.3'
```

Source/target compatibility is set to java 1.8. Error message:

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:    Learn how to resolve the issue at
> >     https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> >     Program type already present: org.hamcrest.BaseDescription

I have anaylyzed dependencies and I found this:

```
compile - Compile dependencies for 'main' sources (deprecated: use 'implementation' instead).
\--- com.rethinkdb:rethinkdb-driver:2.3.3
     +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
     \--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
          \--- junit:junit:4.10
               \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.aress.inshorttest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Call Jar dependencies like this
    implementation files('libs/rethinkdb-driver-2.3.3.jar')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

In the Android Project:

**Path ---> apps> libs > Add Jar Here**
And get JAR File From here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rethinkdb/rethinkdb-driver/2.3.3